# Are there any existing models to aid in extracting shot chart data from game video?

Tags: computer-vision, data-extraction

I'm currently struggling with extracting data by way of basketball game footage captured from the traditional ['broadcast'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRCyMjItEQM&list=PLOFzdcCQWzd2rt1BuMMEdzdVHUKTQVA2S&index=9) camera angle. Since the perspective is warped it is obviously not straight-forward to get coordinates on the court for each shot, but I was wondering whether a relevant model was available for this purpose? If not, does anyone who has experience with this sort of analysis have recommendations for a methodology to adopt?